# Python mapper for adjacent pairs

Tags: python, mapreduce, stdin

I am trying to write a mapreduce program, this is the map part, that returns bigrams or adjacent word pairs from a stdin text.

This is my concept/half-pseudo:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()

    for pair in words: #HERE***
        print '%s\t%s' % (pair,1)
```

How can I **extract an adjacent pair of words** so that I can output all the adjacent word pairs such as "word1 word2, 1" so that in my reducer I can combine them? I'd like to keep the format as close to this as possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pair them like so:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you. Right now, if the line only has one word it output a blank pair [], how can I get rid of that/only have it display when they are there?

Comment: How about just an if statement. `if there is more than one word`, then you pair them, otherwise, just print out that word/do sth else.